# Auto populate global list with the Versions created in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, workitem

Is there a way to auto populate the Work Item Global list with the versions created in TFS 2015. Similar to the one for list of builds as mentioned in the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms194965.aspx

Builds and global list auto-population
The first time you queue a build for a team project using Team Foundation Build, TFS automatically adds a global list labeled “Build - .” Each time a build is run, a LISTITEM is added to this global list with the name of the build.
By adding a GLOBALLIST element to the FIELD definition, you can provide a drop-down menu of builds that users can choose from. For example:

```
<FIELD name="Found In" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Build.FoundIn" type="String" reportable="dimension">
<HELPTEXT>Product build number (revision) in which this item was found</HELPTEXT>
    <SUGGESTEDVALUES>
      <LISTITEM value="&lt;None&gt;" />
    </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
    <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
      <GLOBALLIST name="Builds - TeamProjectName" />
    </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
```

Comment: `with the versions created in TFS 2015` What's the detail mean of version ? Are you meaning the build version  or the version of global list?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Auto populate Versions WorkItem in global list not the build version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS does not provide auto population of Versions into GlobalList.xml, have to update globallist.xml manually or through custom program.